# UICollectionview dynamic height issue

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewlayout

I want to achieve the following outcome[image]

I have implemented `collectionview` horizontal scrolling. It is working fine when scrolling is enabled. However, when scrolling is disabled and the flow changes to vertical, only the first row is displayed and collection view height is not increased.

Q:- How can I get collection view full height when scrolling is disabled?

I have tried the following code for getting height and it returns `30.0`.

```
let height = self.collectionTags.collectionViewLayout.collectionViewContentSize.height; // 30.0
```

And this one returns `0.0`

```
let height = self.collectionTags.contentSize.height // 0.0
```

Here is the collectionview layout code

```
if let flowLayout = collectionTags.collectionViewLayout as? UICollectionViewFlowLayout {
    flowLayout.estimatedItemSize = CGSize(width: 1, height: 30.0)
    flowLayout.itemSize = UICollectionViewFlowLayoutAutomaticSize
}
```

Comment: I think you want to get token field like output. please look at [this](https://github.com/whitesmith/WSTagsField)

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar problem. The solution for me was to add `height constraint` to the collectionView and calculating its height depending on the items that I wanted to display. Here is a snippet I created:

```
// Items that will be displayed inside CollectionView are called tags here
// Total tags width
var tagWidth:CGFloat = 0

// Loop through array of tags
for tag in self.tagsArray {

  // Specifying font so we can calculate dimensions
  let tagFont = UIFont(name: "Cabin-Bold", size: 17)!
  let tagAttributes: [String : Any]? = [
    NSFontAttributeName: tagFont,
    NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.white,
    ]

  // Get text size
  let tagString = tag as NSString
  let textSize = tagString.size(attributes: tagAttributes ?? nil)

  // Add current tag width + padding to the total width
  tagWidth += (textSize.width + 10)
}

// Calculate number of rows
var totalRows = tagWidth / (self.bounds.width - 40)
totalRows = totalRows.rounded(.up)

// Calculate height and apply it to the CollectionView height constraint
estimatedCollectionViewHeight = Float(CGFloat(totalRows * 29))
collectionViewHeight.constant = CGFloat(estimatedCollectionViewHeight)
```